# Multiple jquery dropdown menus on 1 page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

I'm new to jquery and i'm trying to make a dropdown menu list like on [www.teefury.com](http://www.teefury.com) (mens and woman sizes). I came pretty close but when i click 1 of the buttons all of them open (or on my second try only the first one). Thus my questions:

- Does anyone know a tutorial i can use for this?
- What's the best way to try and create one on my own? (i have the html & css ready)
- How do i make it so only 1 of the dropdowns will open on click and not all of them or only the first one?

This is what i have so far: http://users.telenet.be/ezarto/dropdown/

*PS: this is also my first stackoverflow, please inform me of anything i did wrong :)*

*PSS: only 1 hyperlink allowed, sorry but you'll have to copy/paste the teefury one*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *this* and tranverse the DOM to hit the appropriate list that you are trying to show.  I refactored your JavaScript to do so.

```
$(function() {

 $(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
   $(this).closest('dt').siblings('dd').find('ul').toggle();
 });

 $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
   var text = $(this).text();

   $(this).closest('dd').siblings('dt').find('span').text(text);

   $(this).closest('ul').hide();
 });

});​
```

Comment: I also added this

                $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
                    var $clicked = $(e.target);
                    if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown"))
                        $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
                });

to make the menu close on a click anywhere on the screen

Answer (score 0):

**demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/QznH7/

**css**

```
.invisible
{
    display:none;
}​
```

**html**

```
<dl>
        <dt><a class='showMenu' href="javascript:"><span>1</span></a></dt>
        <dd>
            <ul class="invisible">
                <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
</dl>

<dl>
        <dt><a class='showMenu' href="javascript:"><span>2</span></a></dt>
        <dd>
            <ul class="invisible">
                <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>
```

​

**javascript**

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.showMenu').bind('click',function(e){
        jQuery(e.target).parents('dl:first').find('ul').toggleClass('invisible')
    });   
});
```

​

Comment: Very useful answer, gave me a little more insight. I picked the above answer though because it was easier to implement. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Your dropdown menus got the same class `dl class="dropdown">`

So when you do that for example :

```
$(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
  $(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();
});
```

It does it on both of them!

You may want to recognize which one you click on. For example, you can give you dropdowns an id

```
<dl id="dropdown1">
```

and change your jQuery in consequence.

Comment: Yeah i knew that was a problem but didn't really know a way to work around it. Thanks for your answer!